# nginx reverse proxy for docker service

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I have a simple reverse proxy nginx.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

  gzip on;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host            $host:$server_port

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.local;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
  }
}
```

`localhost:3000` is a docker swarm (1.13) service node app. Everything works great initially, when I request `app.local`. However whenever I update a service (containers are redeployed):

`docker service update --force app`

Nginx will think something is wrong (temporarily), and doesn't respond to requests to `app.local` for 30 seconds or so. This is all running on a CentOS 7 server.

I've configured my docker service to redeploy via rolling updates, so from the outside, 3000 never appears to go down. I can continually request `app.local:3000`, bypassing nginx with out any perceived downtime.

Nginx is NOT running in a docker container. I've gotta be missing some sort of configuration option.

Comment: ugh, I just realized this might be more of a serverfault question...

Comment: FWIW, I've essentially fixed the problem by moving my load balancer to a different VM/IP, and using haproxy instead of nginx